# How to handle special letters(\n, \) when decoding base64 encoded json object?

Tags: javascript, python, json, base64

In JavaScript, I used follow code to make Base64 String from Json object

```
let inputJson  = { ... }
let objJsonStr = JSON.stringify(inputJson);
let objJsonB64 = Buffer.from(objJsonStr).toString('base64');
```

And in Server side, I decode it using following code.

```
json.loads(base64.b64decode(objJsonB64))
```

But I have some interesting problem.
I made inputJson from `input` field and if `input` field contains special letters, then decoded value is different with original `input` field's value.

For example, I inputed `test\ntest` but I got `test\\ntest` on backend side.
Because when I make base64 string in Frontend side, JSON.stringify() function encode as follow:

```
\b -> \\b 
\f -> \\f
\n -> \\n
\r -> \\r
\t -> \\t
\" -> \\"
\\ -> \\\\
```

So, when decoding it on backendside, result was different with original one.
But when I use inputJSON with static value, all things works perfectly.
Problem occurs when I make original json with special letters from `input`.
Who ever seen similar problems?

Comment: backslash is an escape character in JSON, so it needs to be escaped to send it literally. This should all be handled transparently by the encoders and decoders of JSON and base 64, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: How are yo uviewing the string in Python? You're looking at the string's representation, which also escapes backslashes. The double backslash is not really in the string.

Comment: Output is same as input. That's the beauty of `.value` and `.textContent`. `\n` would be a new line otherwise.

Comment: Of course, If I used it for representation, `\n` could same as `\\n`.
but my problem is that `input` was used for handling password.
So, I need it to be same as original form value.